# Error while uploading file asynchronously

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to upload file using ajax as below

Here is my html code:

```
<form id="upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form"
   method="POST">
   <input type="file" name="image" id="file-data" />
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top:10px;">
   <a style="color:#fff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:15px;">Submit</a>
   </button>
 </form>
```

jquery code:

```
   $("#upload-file").on('submit', function(e){             
     var formURL="fileupload.php";
     $('#message').html('Uploading File...');
     $("#message").css("display","");
     $.ajax(
     {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {   
          if (data) 
           {
            console.log(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#file-name span").html("");
            $("#file-size span").html("");
            $("#file-type span").html("");
            //$("#file-error").html("");
            $("#file-name span").html(obj['name']);
            $("#file-size span").html(obj['size']);
            $("#file-type span").html(obj['type']);
            //$("#file-error").html(obj['error']);
            $("#file-name").css("display","");
           } 
          },
        });
      });
```

php code:

```
  <?php
   require('db_connect.php');
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  //$errors= array();
  $file['name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  //echo $file['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file['size'] = $file_size/1000;
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file['type']=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("pdf");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $file['error']="extension not allowed, please choose a pdf file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
     $file['error']='File size must be excately 2 MB';
 }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"fileoploaded/".$file_name);
  }
  else{
     $file['error'] = "File could'nt be updates";
  }
}
 $data = json_encode($file, true);
 //echo "done!";
 echo  $data;
 ?>
```

But i am getting following error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. 
    To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in 
   <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b>
```

I can change max_input_vars to some higher value in case of large data
   where i can guess the data before but not in case of file uploaded by user,
   is there any other way to resolve this issue without changing
   max_input_vars in php.ini?

Comment: Please include your PHP code.

Comment: Perhaps restart your server to reflect the php.ini change?

Comment: i do not want to change php.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `contentType: false` in `$.ajax` parameters.
Otherwise jquery will set it's default contentType ( default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, with binary data in body it will split file to billion separate parts).